# I don't know how to put a placeholder

Tags: themes

Okay so, I currently am using a theme called Melos. It has 3 default placeholders. But I don't know how to make a post as placeholder or put a current post in that placeholder. I checked the code too but couldn't find it. Tho, it should have nothing about the code I assume. What I mean is, I can post as a normal entry but I don't know how to set a post to a placeholder. There is no option in any page. Someone please help.

Comment: Have you contacted Melos theme support? I am unfamiliar with the concept of a placeholder post that isn't just a normal post called placeholder, can you be more specific?

Comment: It is not the place for this kinda question. Please read this very carefully. http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your `functions.php`

```
function wpb_change_title_text( $title ){
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if  ( 'post' == $screen->post_type ) {
      $title = 'Post Title';
    }
return $title;
}
add_filter( 'enter_title_here', 'wpb_change_title_text' );
```

The above code will Place "`Post Title`" as placeholder text in `dashboard -> posts -> Add New`. Replace that text with your text and also Replace `post` with your Post-type.

For more detail [read this article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-replace-enter-title-here-text-in-wordpress/)